# NSolve fails with two-dimensional interpolation

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation

I have an interpolating function that takes two arguments. I would like to solve for the case when both arguments are equal, and the interrelated value is some constant. I can plot the interpolating function without problem,

```
Plot[interp[x, x], {x, .1, .9}]
```

[image]

and it clearly equals 10 at some value of x.

But when I try to solve for that value,

```
NSolve[interp[x, x] == 10, x]
```

it returns unevaluated.

If I set one of the arguments to a constant, it works fine.

```
NSolve[interp[x, .4] == 10, x]

{{x -> 0.418182}}
```

Any ideas as to why NSolve doesn't work in this case?

In response to those who asked for the actual interpolation, here is an example:

```
    pts = {{{{0., 0.}, 58.4336}, {{0., 0.1}, 57.7826}, {{0., 0.2}, 
   56.9961}, {{0., 0.3}, 56.0213}, {{0., 0.4}, 54.7733}, {{0., 0.5}, 
   53.1054}, {{0., 0.6}, 49.6639}, {{0., 0.7}, 41.9365}, {{0., 0.8}, 
   30.4374}, {{0., 0.9}, 13.8417}}, {{{0.1, 0.}, 
   45.2018}, {{0.1, 0.1}, 44.6079}, {{0.1, 0.2}, 
   43.8945}, {{0.1, 0.3}, 43.0163}, {{0.1, 0.4}, 
   41.9013}, {{0.1, 0.5}, 40.4266}, {{0.1, 0.6}, 
   37.5209}, {{0.1, 0.7}, 30.9379}, {{0.1, 0.8}, 21.726}, {{0.1, 0.9},
    9.35026}}, {{{0.2, 0.}, 32.4311}, {{0.2, 0.1}, 
   31.9461}, {{0.2, 0.2}, 31.3661}, {{0.2, 0.3}, 
   30.6561}, {{0.2, 0.4}, 29.7604}, {{0.2, 0.5}, 
   28.5857}, {{0.2, 0.6}, 26.366}, {{0.2, 0.7}, 21.2549}, {{0.2, 0.8},
    14.466}, {{0.2, 0.9}, 5.88147}}, {{{0.3, 0.}, 
   21.2598}, {{0.3, 0.1}, 20.9066}, {{0.3, 0.2}, 
   20.4858}, {{0.3, 0.3}, 19.9728}, {{0.3, 0.4}, 
   19.3291}, {{0.3, 0.5}, 18.4904}, {{0.3, 0.6}, 
   16.9657}, {{0.3, 0.7}, 13.3778}, {{0.3, 0.8}, 
   8.82288}, {{0.3, 0.9}, 3.36398}}, {{{0.4, 0.}, 
   12.4359}, {{0.4, 0.1}, 12.2095}, {{0.4, 0.2}, 
   11.9404}, {{0.4, 0.3}, 11.6136}, {{0.4, 0.4}, 
   11.2053}, {{0.4, 0.5}, 10.6759}, {{0.4, 0.6}, 
   9.74796}, {{0.4, 0.7}, 7.5085}, {{0.4, 0.8}, 4.78097}, {{0.4, 0.9},
    1.67922}}, {{{0.5, 0.}, 6.2246}, {{0.5, 0.1}, 
   6.10026}, {{0.5, 0.2}, 5.95296}, {{0.5, 0.3}, 
   5.77456}, {{0.5, 0.4}, 5.55249}, {{0.5, 0.5}, 
   5.26598}, {{0.5, 0.6}, 4.78091}, {{0.5, 0.7}, 
   3.57892}, {{0.5, 0.8}, 2.17599}, {{0.5, 0.9}, 
   0.675656}}, {{{0.6, 0.}, 2.44927}, {{0.6, 0.1}, 
   2.39436}, {{0.6, 0.2}, 2.32949}, {{0.6, 0.3}, 
   2.25118}, {{0.6, 0.4}, 2.15409}, {{0.6, 0.5}, 
   2.02947}, {{0.6, 0.6}, 1.82565}, {{0.6, 0.7}, 
   1.30923}, {{0.6, 0.8}, 0.737839}, {{0.6, 0.9}, 
   0.181827}}, {{{0.7, 0.}, 0.614049}, {{0.7, 0.1}, 
   0.597373}, {{0.7, 0.2}, 0.577752}, {{0.7, 0.3}, 
   0.554189}, {{0.7, 0.4}, 0.525162}, {{0.7, 0.5}, 
   0.488219}, {{0.7, 0.6}, 0.429796}, {{0.7, 0.7}, 
   0.282032}, {{0.7, 0.8}, 0.133361}, {{0.7, 0.9}, 
   0.0170173}}, {{{0.8, 0.}, 0.0434144}, {{0.8, 0.1}, 
   0.0414826}, {{0.8, 0.2}, 0.0392407}, {{0.8, 0.3}, 
   0.0365942}, {{0.8, 0.4}, 0.0334052}, {{0.8, 0.5}, 
   0.0294674}, {{0.8, 0.6}, 0.0235791}, {{0.8, 0.7}, 
   0.0104773}, {{0.8, 0.8}, 0.00174651}, {{0.8, 0.9}, 
   0}}, {{{0.9, 0.}, 0}, {{0.9, 0.1}, 0}, {{0.9, 0.2}, 
   0}, {{0.9, 0.3}, 0}, {{0.9, 0.4}, 0}, {{0.9, 0.5}, 0}, {{0.9, 0.6},
    0}, {{0.9, 0.7}, 0}, {{0.9, 0.8}, 0}, {{0.9, 0.9}, 0}}};

interp = Interpolation[Flatten[pts, 1]];
threshold = 5;
NSolve[interp[x, x] == threshold, x]
```

Comment: Try `NSolve[{interp[x, x] == 10, 0.1 < x < 0.9}, x]`. If that doesn't work, use `FindRoot`, or you need to provide the interpolating function for us to work with.

Comment: FindRoot does work, thanks! Though I am still curious why Solve does not.

Comment: From their documentation, `Solve` and `NSolve` deal primarily with linear and polynomial equations. `FindRoot` works for more complicated equations; however, it only finds a single solution for a given initial estimate.

Comment: I think this goes astray because `NSolve` is a hybrid function that does both symbolic and numeric work, and seeks all solutions. `FindRoot` is really the more natural choice. That stated, one can fool `NSolve` a bit by forcing it to treat this as a purely numeric black box type of function. `ff[x_?NumericQ] := interp[x,x];NSolve[ff[x]==threshold, x]                                             

NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may
     not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

Out[6]= {{x -> 0.505948}}`

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to find the roots.

- `FindRoot`

```
FindRoot[{interp[x, y] == 5, y == x}, {x, 0}, {y, 0}]
```

> `{x -> 0.505948, y -> 0.505948}`

```
FindRoot[{interp[x, x] == 5}, {x, 0}]
```

> `{x -> 0.505948}`

- `DiscretizeRegion`.

Since `FindRoot` only find one root at one time, here we provide region method or othere graphis method to find many roots.

```
Clear[reg,dreg];
reg = ImplicitRegion[{interp[x, y] == .5, y == x}, {x, y}];
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg, interp["Domain"]];
result = MeshPrimitives[dreg, 0]
result[[;; , 1, 1]]
```

> `{Point[{0.505948, 0.505948}]}`

> `{0.675757}`

- Another example.

```
Clear[pts, interp, reg, dreg];
pts = Flatten[
   Table[Evaluate[{{x, y}, Sin[x y], D[Sin[x y], {{x, y}}]}], {x, 0, 
     3, 1.}, {y, 0, 3, 1.}], 1];
interp = Interpolation[pts];
reg = ImplicitRegion[{interp[x, y] == .5, y == x}, {x, y}];
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg, interp["Domain"]];
result = MeshPrimitives[dreg, 0]
result[[;; , 1, 1]]
```

> `{0.734037, 1.59182, 2.691, 2.98277}`

```
Plot[interp[x, x], {x, 0, 3}, Mesh -> {result[[;; , 1, 1]]}, 
 MeshStyle -> Red, GridLines -> {None, {.5}}]
```

[image]